# Python 3.8, Как разделить bot.command и bot.event?

Tags: python, discord

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(bot.user.name)
    print(bot.user.id)
    print('------')

bot.remove_command('help')

@bot.command()
async def Помощь(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Яблочный бот", description="Действительно сладкий бот. Лист команд ниже:", color=0xeee657)

    embed.add_field(name="$Информация", value="Даёт информацию о боте", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="$Помощь", value="Выдаёт это-же сообщение с командами", inline=False)

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

@bot.command()
async def Информация(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Яблочный бот", description="Действительно сладкий бот.", color=0xeee657)

    embed.add_field(name="$Автор", value="ChillAple#5740")
    embed.add_field(name="Инфо о боте", value="Это развлекательный бот, который будет играть с вами в мини игры и уметь управлять вашим сервером.")

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

@bot.event()
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('Фото на рабочий стол с водопадами'):
        print('[command]: photo с водопадами')
        await message.channel.send('ссылка')
    if message.content.startswith('Фото на рабочий стол с лесом'):
        print('[command]: photo с лесом')
        await message.channel.send('ссылка')
    if message.content.startswith('Фото на рабочий стол с горами'):
        print('[command]: photo с горами')
        await message.channel.send('ссылка')
    if message.content.startswith('Фото на рабочий стол с рисунками'):
        print('[command]: photo с рисунками')
        await message.channel.send('ссылка')
    if message.content.startswith('Фото на рабочий стол с горами'):
        print('[command]: photo с горами')
        await message.channel.send('ссылка')
    if message.content.startswith('Фото на рабочий стол с деревьями'):
        print('[command]: photo с деревьями')
        await message.channel.send('https://imgur.com/t/desktop_backgrounds/zuk7dWD')
    if message.content.startswith('Фото на рабочий стол с рисунками'):
        print('[command]: photo с рисунками')
        await message.channel.send('ссылка')
    if message.content.startswith('Фото на рабочий стол с листьями'):
        print('[command]: photo с листьями')
        await message.channel.send('ссылка')
    if message.content.startswith('Фото на рабочий стол с рисунками'):
        print('[command]: photo с рисунками')
        await message.channel.send('ссылка')
    if message.content.startswith('!Фото на рабочий стол с рисунками'):
        print('[command]: photo с рисунками')
        await message.channel.send('ссылка')
    if message.content.startswith('Фото на рабочий стол с любовью'):
        print('[command]: photo с любовью')
        await message.channel.send('ссылка')
    if message.content.startswith('Фото на рабочий стол с рисунками'):
        print('[command]: photo с рисунками')
        await message.channel.send('ссылка')
    if message.content.startswith('Фото на рабочий стол с рисунками'):
        print('[command]: photo с рисунками')
        await message.channel.send('ссылка')
    if message.content.startswith('очистка'):
        print('[command]: чистка')
        await message.channel.send(' !clear 10 ')    

bot.run('TOKEN')
```

В данном случае столкнулся с проблемой, что Бот видит только bot.event, обе bot.command он не реагирует, как в данном случае совместить сообщения так, чтоб каждая работала по своей команде? Пишу бота на Discord, в случае если все три будут command то в последнем блоке он не будет определять команду.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте:

```py
await bot.process_commands(message)
```

В функцию on_message:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    await bot.process_commands(message)
    ...
```

Ссылка на аналогичную ошибку в github (с этим решением): https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/186

Comment: Помогло, но не совсем, теперь бот постоянно реагирует на это сообщение, тем самым присылаем сообщения на команду постоянно.

Answer (score 0):

Дополнение к предыдущему ответу: Добавьте просто проверку, что сообщение не от бота, например **not message.author.bot**

**example:**

```
async def on_message(message):
    await bot.process_commands(message) 
    if not message.author.bot:
    ...
```